# Extracting the (i) estimated variance-covariance matrix of random effects and/or (ii) mixed model equation solutions from lme4 as matrices?

Tags: r, sas, lme4, mixed-models, nlme

As the title says I am trying to extract matrices from an lme4 (or other packages?) object. To make clear what I want precisely I think it is easiest to refer to the SAS documentation: https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63033/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect022.htm

**Variance-covariance matrix of random effects**

In SAS notation this matrix is called *G* and is the variance-covariance matrix of the random effect parameter *gamma*. By using the option "G" in PROC MIXED and  the Output Delivery System you obtain *G* as a matrix.

I am aware that it is relatively simple to construct this matrix manually once I have the variance components and dimensions of gamma. I nevertheless expected there to be an even simpler way.

**Mixed model equations solution**

In SAS notation these are called *C*.
By using the option "MMEQSOL" in PROC MIXED and  the Output Delivery System you request that a solution to the mixed model equations be produced, as well as the inverted coefficients matrix. It is the latter that I am interested in.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a very sensible model (see `?lme4::cake`), but reasonable for illustration:

```
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(angle ~ temperature + 
           (1|recipe)+(1|replicate), cake)
```

The `VarCorr()` method gives a *list* of variance-covariance matrices for each term (in this case each one is 1x1), with its own print method:

```
v <- VarCorr(fm1)
```

You can combine these into a single matrix by using the `bdiag()` (block-diagonal) function from `Matrix` (`as.matrix()` converts from a sparse matrix to a standard (dense) R matrix object).

```
as.matrix(Matrix::bdiag(v))
##          [,1]      [,2]
## [1,] 39.21541 0.0000000
## [2,]  0.00000 0.4949681
```

The C matrix is unfortunately not so easy to get. As discussed in `vignette("lmer",package="lme4")`, `lme4` doesn't use the Henderson-equation formulation. The upper block of C (variance-covariance matrix of fixed effects) is accessible via `vcov()`, but the variance-covariance matrix of the variances is not so easy: see e.g. [here](https://rpubs.com/bbolker/varwald).

Comment: Thanks, Ben! Is there a corresponding code to get the same from `glmmTMB`?